# Convert historical stock prices from Yahoo finance to a different currency with Python

Tags: python, stock, price

I am trying to adjust the historical stock price of non-euro listed firms to euro. Hence, I would like to convert the stock price of Apple to euro. I have scraped the historical exchange rates as well as the historical adjusted stock prices. I have now two data-frames, the first data-frame shows the currency of the stock and the stock price. I use multiple stocks for my portfolio. I do so by using this code:

```
assets =  ["^AEX", "AAPL", "AZN.L", "AD.AS ", "ASML.AS"]
```

.

```
                     ^AEX   AAPL    AZN.L   AD.AS   ASML.AS    idx
                      EUR   USD     GBP     EUR     EUR         currency
2021-02-02 00:00:00 652.87  134.789 51.46   23.54   457.5       NaN
2021-02-03 00:00:00 654.89  133.74  51.42   23.6    457.15      NaN
2021-02-04 00:00:00 654.38  137.185 50.84   23.46   459.55      NaN
2021-02-05 00:00:00 653.24  136.76  51      23.35   460         NaN
2021-02-08 00:00:00 656.39  135.942 51.48   23.3    467.1       NaN
```

The second data-frame shows the historical exchange rate data.

```
       Currency code    Currency name   Units per EUR   EUR per Unit    Date
0   0   USD             US Dollar       1.320339        0.757381    2021-02-03
1   1   EUR             Euro            1.000000        1.000000    2021-02-03
2   2   GBP             British Pound   0.812044        1.231461    2021-02-03
3   3   INR             Indian Rupee    72.359647       0.013820    2021-02-03
4   4   AUD             Australian Dollar 1.269889      0.787470    2021-02-03
```

The idea is now to merge both frames, and to show the stock price in euro. I think we have to put both dates in the merged data-frame.

We need a for loop to identify if the stock is not in euro, search for a match in date, search for a match in currency code, and if the currency code is for instance US dollar, then multiply the stock * 0.757381 (if the stock date is 2012-02-03 in data-frame 1).

If the stock is in euro, we can multiply *1. If the stock price is for instance in GBP then multiply *1.231461.

The ideal situation would be to have a new data-frame with only the date and the stock price in euro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer has a bug in the code.

This line:

```
stock_df = pd.concat([stock_df, data], axis=0)
```

should be indented to the same level as the if and elif statements, otherwise the results from the last loop always overwrite the previous.

EDIT 2:
Another issue in the answer is that the exchange rates should multiply the price in the original currency instead of dividing... In other words the loops should be doing this:

```
data['price'] = data['Close'] * data['rating']
```

Answer (score 1):

To deal with such a case, we can

1. To combine stock price and exchange rate after acquiring them separately
2. Acquire the exchange rate at the same time as the stock price is acquired and store it in the data frame.

These approaches may differ depending on the number of stocks and currencies to be acquired, and the period to be covered.
The approach I have taken is the latter type, where the stock price and exchange rate are acquired and stored at the time of acquisition.

The reason is that the exchange rate does not change in the past, so the rate is acquired at the time of acquisition and converted to the base rate. We believe this effect will reduce the amount of code and the only reuse of the data will be extraction.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

start = '2020-07-01'
end = '2021-01-01'

rates = ['USDEUR=X', 'GBPEUR=X']
tickers = yf.Tickers(' '.join(rates))

exchange_rates = []
for i in tickers.tickers:
    exchange_rates.append(tickers.tickers[i].history(start=start, end=end).Close)

ex_df = pd.DataFrame(exchange_rates).T
ex_df.columns = rates
ex_df['EUREUR=X'] = 1.0

assets = {'^AEX':'EUR', 'AAPL':'USD', 'AZN.L':'GBP', 'AD.AS':'EUR', 'ASML.AS':'EUR'}

stock_df = pd.DataFrame()
for k,v in assets.items():
    data = yf.download(k, start=start, end=end, progress=False).Close.to_frame()
    data['ticker'] = k
    if v[:3] == 'EUR':
        data['rating'] = ex_df['EUREUR=X']
        data['price'] = data['Close'] / data['rating'] 
    elif v[:3] == 'USD':
        data['rating'] = ex_df['USDEUR=X']
        data['price'] = data['Close'] / data['rating'] 
    elif v[:3] == 'GBP':
        data['rating'] = ex_df['GBPEUR=X']
        data['price'] = data['Close'] / data['rating'] 
    else:
        data['rating'] = np.NaN
        data['price'] = np.NaN
stock_df = pd.concat([stock_df, data], axis=0)

stock_df
    Close   ticker  rating  price
Date                
2020-06-30  559.729980  ^AEX    1.0     559.729980
2020-07-01  562.669983  ^AEX    1.0     562.669983
2020-07-02  570.750000  ^AEX    1.0     570.750000
2020-07-03  568.630005  ^AEX    1.0     568.630005
2020-07-06  578.520020  ^AEX    1.0     578.520020
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2020-12-24  393.500000  ASML.AS     1.0     393.500000
2020-12-28  396.850006  ASML.AS     1.0     396.850006
2020-12-29  396.299988  ASML.AS     1.0     396.299988
2020-12-30  398.500000  ASML.AS     1.0     398.500000
2020-12-31  397.549988  ASML.AS     1.0     397.549988

stock_df.loc[stock_df['ticker'] == 'AAPL'].head()

    Close   ticker  rating  price

    Close   ticker  rating  price
Date                
2020-06-30  91.199997   AAPL    0.88911     102.574478
2020-07-01  91.027496   AAPL    0.89000     102.278087
2020-07-02  91.027496   AAPL    0.88878     102.418480
2020-07-06  93.462502   AAPL    0.88911     105.119162
2020-07-07  93.172501   AAPL    0.88395     105.404719
```

Comment: first of all, many thanks. How do I add the data of the adjusted price, in order to plot the data?

Comment: it is not a complete different question, but I did not mention it. The question will be to add the date in order to plot and analyse the data. I have posted the question, where I changed the period from 2013 onwards, I don't know if that impacts your code.

Comment: I just checked the new question and noticed it. The date had been omitted, so I fixed the code. I think the new question also needs to be fixed. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: No problem at all, the only remaining issue is that I am not able to plot the data correctly. Is it possible to set first column only the data, and next to that the name of the tickers?  Date               AEX':', 'AAPL''AZN.L':'AD.AS' 'ASML.AS'                                                                                           d                    2020-07-01   300     200     200       200       200

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you want to graph it that way; if the x-axis is a time series and each stock is a line graph, then you need to change the way you have the data. I am not sure about the order of the columns you commented on.

Comment: I have adjusted the other question, I think it is now clear what I mean.

Comment: I am running into a error while  running: exchange_rates = []
for i in range(len(tickers.tickers)):
    exchange_rates.append(tickers.tickers[i].history(start=start, end=end).Close). The error is 
KeyError: 0. I don't understand, I did not receive this error earlier.

Comment: I just tried to run my code now and no error occurred. Are you getting the same exchange rate? If they are different rates, check if you can get them independently. Also, have you upgraded the yfinace module?

Comment: The link is the type that requires access rights, so make it a bottom link that anyone who knows it from sharing can open. You can delete the comment at any time if you are the one who made it.

Comment: Error confirmed. It was the latest version, so I adapted it to the version I was using, but I still got the error. I don't know the cause, but I modified the code so that I could get it. `for i in tickers.tickers:`

Comment: You may delete the above links.

Comment: There is just one more thing to do, we have to multiply the close* price, instead of close/price.

Comment: Why not simply change division to multiplication? Or you could just add a new column.

Comment: I already do so, that is easy. I just told you for other users, if they want to use your code.